# Adding an Array to an Array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

So I have  a db document that holds some string values in an array, I want to push just the array from every entry into an array in the application for usage later, But I can see the array fine on the fetch, and when I iterate it but my "Global array" is staying empty can someone explain why?

```
specialDates : Specialdates[] = [];
specialRange: any[] = [];
```

```
this.specialDates.forEach(ag => {      
//ag,range -> I can see fine
   this.specialRange.push(ag.range);
//this.specialrange -> Stays empty 
});
```

Array looks something like the following:

```
1205,1206,1207,1208
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Reason for doing this is because the documents have 2 fields minimum: EG ->
ID/Array

And I just need the array

Comment: can you try this and see what does it display? `this.specialRange = [...this.specialDates]`

Comment: this.specialRange = this.specialDates.map(ag => ag.range)

Comment: How is `this.specialDates` initialized? Is it async?

Comment: @lazizanie That works thank you, And it get initialized on fetch

Comment: @lazizanie post as answer to get credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.specialRange = this.specialDates.map(ag => ag.range)